# Error: Incompatible types: got "VOID" expected "LONGINT" in Pascal using Dev-Pascal

Tags: pascal

I am creating a project which convert binary number to decimal number. Here is the code :

```
program binerdesimal;
uses crt;
var
  p, d, i, l, pow, int:integer;
  x:real;
  y:integer;
  b:string;
begin
  readln(b);
  d:=0;

  for i:=1 to length(b) do
  begin
    l:=length(b);
    l:=l - 1;
    pow := power(2, l);
    int := val(b[i], x, y);
    d := d + (int * pow);
  end;

  writeln(d);
  readln;
end.
```

The input number is b and b itself is a string because I want to access the index of the binary number. Example : 1011 then b[1] = 1; b[2] = 0; b[3] = 1; b[4] = 1. The decimal number of 1011 is (1*2^3) + (0*2^2) + (1*2^1) + (1*2^0)

If I use b as integer, it can't.

I use val to convert a string to integer but an error appeared : 
Error: Incompatible types: got "VOID" expected "LONGINT" in Pascal using Dev-Pascal
pointed at :

```
int := val(b[i], x, y);
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: `Val` doesn't return anything. Instead it places the output into `x`, or optionally an index into `y` if the conversion failed.

Comment: So how do I convert a string to integer and the integer can be used in calculation ? @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
I have changed the code
`val(b[i], x, y);`
`d:= d + (x * pow);`
And still didn't work

Comment: "didn't work", what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I mean an error appeared `Error: Incompatible types: got "S80REAL" expected "LONGINT"
`

Comment: Try changing the type of `x` to ´LONGINT`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Nice ! It works perfectly thanks :)